# C# ODBCDataReader reading null data and null date values

Tags: c#, odbc, db2

I'm reading a record from a DB2 database via ODBC connection.  The data is populated into an ODBCDataReader.  As I'm going through my foreach loop I'm running into problems trying to parse the multiple different DateTime fields.

Some of the fields are null, some have null date time value (9999-12-31 24:00:00.000000) and some have valid date time values (2010-07-09 20:43:32.037234).

I've tried doing something like this to catch null date time errors:

```
if (!dr[dbFieldName].Equals(DBNull.Value))
{
  if (dr.GetDate(dr.GetOrdinal(dbFieldName)).Equals(DateTime.Parse("9999-12-31 24:00:00.000000")))
  {
    fieldValues[tag] = "";
  }
  else
  {
    strValue = dr.GetDate(dr.GetOrdinal(dbFieldName)).ToString("s");
    fieldValues[tag] = strValue.Trim();
  }
}
```

The GetType().Name != "DBNull" seems to work for catching null values.  However the next if statement throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error.  This appears to happen on fields with the 9999-12-31 24:00:00.000000 values.

Is there a way to properly parse this?  It seems like any way I try to evaluate these null date time fields a error is thrown.

Comment: It looks like I can't touch the dr[dbFieldName] field without the ArgumentOutOfRangeException from being thrown when that field contains a time value of 24:00:00.000000.

Comment: Ok well it looks like I found a solution.  Instead of selecting these DateTime fields from the database as a timestamp, I'll select them as a String.  Then I can parse the values as needed and put them into a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Jerod's comment.

```
DateTime.Parse("9999-12-31 23:59:00.000000") is valid
DateTime.Parse("9999-12-31 24:00:00.000000") is invalid
```

update....

The problem is 24:00 is not considered a valid time in the 24 hour clock (regardless of date). You may be able to work around that by using

```
    DateTime.ParseExact("9999-12-31 24:00:00.000000", "yyyy-MM-dd 24:mm:ss.ffffff",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

after a DateTime.TryParse method. If TryParse succeeds, you have a valid date. If it returns false, the above statemen tis executed.

Comment: The question is would now be, since "9999-12-31 24:00:00.000000" is invalid as a DateTime value, and apparently is what my ODBCDataReader contains, how would I get that value out?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Use the DBNull.Value object to check for null.
2) Use DateTime.MaxValue to check 12/31/999 24:00:00.

Hopefully that will help you get closer to finding the problem.

Comment: Updated my code with suggestion #1.  DateTime.MaxValue is readonly and says that 23:59.00 is the maximum as Raj Kaimal points out above.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the IF/ELSE in a TRY/CATCH.  It's not considered good form, but catching the exception is gauranteed to work.

Comment: This is the route I went with originally, but my Output/Debug window was being flooded with messages about the error being caught.  I'd like to try to find a solution that doesn't involve this method if possible.